AC vs DC supply for ~50ft, ~500mW load from 110VAC
I am looking for the most efficient way to power an ESP8266 micro controller via ~50ft AWG18 low voltage wiring from 110VAC. For the ESP itself I assume a pessimistic 100mA at 3.3V but the board has a 5V-to-3.3 buck and 5V is also used for a sensor. Assuming 70% efficiency, that’s 470mW or 94mA at 5V.
The following options exist to deliver 5V (100mA current):

AC. For example, use a 24V doorbell transformer and then use rectifier/step down at the other end (for example with module https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B094ZTG5S8)
DC with step down. Use a wall power supply to generate, eg 9V DC and use a step down at the other end (again for example https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B094ZTG5S8) at the destination
Use a 5V USB supply directly

I think (3) is completely out of question.
I think voltage drop is no concern because of my low current levels. 50 ft AWG is ~300mOhm and would result in just tens of mV.
In general, I would expect (1) to be the better option. However, it seems doorbell transformers are notoriously inefficient (why??) Even at no load, the losses are in the Watts range.
Is it generally more efficient to immediately rectify and switch down, as opposed to transforming down and rectifying? Are there any others fundamental issues to consider when deciding between (1) and (2)?

Have you considered PoE for this? Not the Ethernet part, but the power delivery part?

Yes but the cable exist already which is just normal low voltage wiring

AC-DC with a buck converter at the other end seems like a good solution. Modern AC adapters are reasonably efficient. You may have something around you can use as-is that meets proper safety standards.
AWG18 100' round trip is only about 0.6Ω, so less than 100mV drop at 100mA, so the 5V USB adapter will work, but you could have issues from voltage induced in the wires from nearby lighting etc. Using the buck converter will allow a lot more tolerance. At ~100mA a linear regulator is not all that terrible.
Needless to say, if this is going outdoors you'll need to take additional precautions against lightning.
Doorbell transformers are made cheaply, with cheap alloy in the lamination and not very much of it, so they tend to run warm. They also often have poor regulation since they have to be safe when short-circuited, which means the output voltage when lightly loaded may be too high for those hobby buck regulators. (24V * 1.25 * 1.414 is about 42V peak). If you use those modules, I would definitely avoid getting close to the maximum ratings.

Thanks! So you would go for (1) but not with a doorbell transformer? What is the specific reason over DC? And also, can you confirm that (1) is not inherently worse efficiency than (2)? And for the wall AC-AC adapter, they all only specify average efficiency (if even) and no efficiency curves. Is it right that the wattage closer to my operation point will be most efficient? I.e. I should choose 1W supply instead of 10W? Or is the "no load consumption" representative of light load?

For example, https://catalog.triadmagnetics.com/Asset/WAU240-500.pdf is still 210mW without load and 83% average efficiency. Is this as good as it gets practically?

Wall plug adapters are subject to regulation on how efficient they have to be so they generally publish  the efficiency numbers. Raw small power transformers not so much. If I was going for maximum efficiency, I'd probably use a high quality transformer rated for about 5x the actual output power required, but something like  240:24 and run it 120:12. And use Schottky (or ideal) diodes. But you really have to research and compare the numbers under actual operating conditions if you're looking at the last bit. Bridge->cap results in high RMS currents in the transformer, which can be mitigated..

.. with a choke, but that's heavy and expensive and hardly anybody does.
